# find even positions in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
evenPositions([],[]).
evenPositions([X], []).
evenPositions([X, Y|R], [X|Tail1]) :- evenPositions(R,Tail1).
```

I am missing something to get the last single element left in the list while finding the even positions .

When i run evenPositions([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],Z). It is not including g in the list.

Comment: it's because *g* is in position 7. 7 is not even. It's odd. Also, your predicates select the *odd* positions in the list. Why? If you want to select the *odd* position, the second rule has to be changed to `evenPositions([X], [X]).`